# io.Copy: How to know if a socket is closed or disconnected

Tags: sockets, go

I have a simple program that connects a program's stdin, stdout and stderr to a socket, like this,

```
go func() {
    defer conn.Close();
    defer stdin.Close();

    io.Copy(stdin, conn);
}();

go func() {
    defer conn.Close();
    defer stdout.Close();
    defer stderr.Close();

    io.Copy(conn, stdout);
    io.Copy(conn, stderr);
}();

select{}
```

I have two problems,

1. I have to keep these two goroutines running by doing a `select{}`
2. When the socket get disconnected, there's no way to tell it. I need to terminate the `select{}` loop if that happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a difference between 'socket is closed' and 'socket gets disconnected'. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @EJP What do you mean? If it's disconnected, then it's closed, I don't get it ...

Comment: No. If it's disconnected you can still use it, read from it and get end of stream, or write to it and get 'connection reset' errors, etc. It's only closed when *you* close it.

Comment: @EJP Then I want to know both of them

Comment: Then the part about knowing when you've closed your own socket is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If connection is closed, `io.Copy()` will return `(0, io.EOF)`, so you can check it.